# symfony6 - defining and using services.yaml in third part bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony6

I'm making simple "MyCoreBundle" (MystertyCoreBundle) using [symfony6.1 how to make bundle's doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html#creating-a-bundle).

I defined my bundle class vendor/mysterty/core-bundle/CoreBundle.class

```php
<?php

namespace Mysterty\CoreBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\AbstractBundle;

class MystertyCoreBundle extends AbstractBundle
{
}
```

I defined some parameters and configuration in vendor/mysterty/core-bundle/config/services.yaml as defaults :

```yml
services:
  Mysterty\CoreBundle\Controller\CoreController:
    public: true
    calls:
      - method: setContainer
        arguments: ["@service_container"]

parameters:
  app.admin_email: "mymailATserver.com"
```

Then I made simple controller in vendor/mysterty/core-bundle/src/Controller/CoreController.php:

```php
<?php

namespace Mysterty\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class CoreController extends AbstractController
{

    #[Route('/', name: 'mty_default')]
    public function indexNoLocale(): Response
    {
        $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
        $supportedLangs = explode('|', $this->getParameter('app.supported_locales'));
        $lang = in_array($lang, $supportedLangs) ? $lang : $supportedLangs[0];
        return $this->redirectToRoute('mty_home', ['_locale' => $lang]);
    }
```

Finally, i added the bundle's routes to \config\routes.yaml

```yml
mysterty_core:
    resource: "../vendor/mysterty/core-bundle/src/Controller/CoreController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Here is the error i have on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ :

> "Mysterty\CoreBundle\Controller\CoreController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?

I try to make a shared bundle with default actions and components for all my symfony projects.

Comment: You can use `bin/console debug:container CoreController` to see if your controller is being defined as a service.  I suspect not.  You probably need to add a `loadExtension` method to your bundle class to load your services.yaml file.  It's not automatic.  You will probably also have trouble injecting the container as service_container is no longer defined out of the box.  Plus many of it's services are no longer public. Need to look at injecting the container service locator or just autowire the silly thing.

Comment: The trick about the controller service locator is to inject `Psr\Container\ContainerInterface` as the setContainer argument.  Kind of magical but more discussion [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/44628).

Comment: Thx.

I think that in fact, my bundle's services.yaml isn't loaded at all. Nore configurations or parameters are working here and it's why i named my question as it is.

So i put it in app's services.yaml :
``` lang-yaml
  Mysterty\CoreBundle\Controller\CoreController:
    public: true
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    calls:
      - [setContainer, ['@Psr\Container\ContainerInterface']]
    tags:
      - "controller.service_arguments"
      - "container.service_subscriber"
``` 

It helped BUT i still can't load all parameters defined in my bundle's services.yaml.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html#loading-services-directly-in-your-bundle-class  By the way, comments don't format all that well.

Comment: thx @Cerad, i missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by @Cerad

> You can use bin/console debug:container CoreController to see if your
> controller is being defined as a service. I suspect not. You probably
> need to add a loadExtension method to your bundle class to load your
> services.yaml file. It's not automatic. You will probably also have
> trouble injecting the container as service_container is no longer
> defined out of the box. Plus many of it's services are no longer
> public. Need to look at injecting the container service locator or
> just autowire the silly thing.

So : here is **the needed configuration (thx to helpers):**

define loadExtension function in MyOwnBundle.php :

```php
<?php

namespace MyOwn\MyOwnBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\AbstractBundle;

class MyOwnBundle extends AbstractBundle
{
    public function loadExtension(array $config, ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    {
            // load an XML, PHP or Yaml file
            $container->import('../config/services.yaml');
    }
}
```

and the correct services.yaml:

```yaml
// My/CoreBundle/config/services.yaml
services:

  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: true

  My\CoreBundle\Controller\CoreController:
    public: true
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    calls:
      - [setContainer, ['@Psr\Container\ContainerInterface']]
    tags:
      - "controller.service_arguments"
      - "container.service_subscriber"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Symfiony could not `autoconfigure` your controller. Try adding the `#[AsController]` attribute to your controller classes or add `autoconfigure: true` to your controller service definition in your services.yaml

Comment: In general, autowire/autoconfigure is discouraged in bundles.  Plus I'm pretty sure that the main problem is that the bundle's services.yaml file is simple not being loaded at all.

Comment: Thx it helped to access the controller. But it's not solved yet.